# Unable to bind checkbox on dropdown change in .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I am using .NET 6, and I want to bind checkboxes `onchange` event of dropdown. On dropdown `onchange` event, for loop is not executed. When I change the dropdown value, calling the Javascript method, which calls the action method, I get the data in the class object, but for loop is not executed inside the view and my checkbox are not binding.

View model classes:

```
public class UserRoleViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "User")]
    public int? EmployeesEmpId { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public List<RoleAddViewModel> lstRoleAddViewModels { get; set; }
}

public class RoleAddViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Role")]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}
```

Controller code:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult AddUserRole(int UserId = 0)
{
    UserRoleViewModel userRoleviewmodel = new UserRoleViewModel();

    if (UserId == 0)
    {
        var users = _employeeRepository.GetUsers();
        ViewBag.Users = users;
        userRoleviewmodel.lstRoleAddViewModels = _employeeRepository.UserRoles();
    }
    else if (UserId > 0)
    {
        userRoleviewmodel = _employeeRepository.GetUserRole(UserId);
    }

    return View(userRoleviewmodel);
}
```

View markup:

```
@model EmpTest.ViewModel.UserRoleViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "AddUserRole";
}

<h1>AddUserRole</h1>

<h4>UserRoleViewModel</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="AddUserRole">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="EmployeesEmpId" class="control-label"></label>
                @* <input asp-for="UserId" class="form-control" /> *@
                <select asp-for="EmployeesEmpId" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.Users, "EmpId", "Name"))">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="EmployeesEmpId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                @for (var i = 0; i <= Model.lstRoleAddViewModels.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.lstRoleAddViewModels[i].Checked" />
                    <label asp-for="@Model.lstRoleAddViewModels[i].Checked">@Model.lstRoleAddViewModels[i].RoleName</label>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.lstRoleAddViewModels[i].RoleId" />
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.lstRoleAddViewModels[i].RoleName" />
                    <br />
                }
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Add Role" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
    <script>
        $('#EmployeesEmpId').change(function () {
            debugger;
            var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "Employee/AddUserRole";
            var source = '#EmployeesEmpId';
            $.getJSON(url, { UserId: $(source).val() }, function (data) {
                // var items = '';

            });
        });

    </script>
}
```

Please help

Comment: "which calls the action method, I get the data in the class object, when for loop is not executed inside the view and my checkbox are not binding"  Do you mean you can get the data in AddUserRole(int UserId = 0) ? What do you mean checkbox are not binding?

Comment: If you want to change the checkbox  depend on dropdown change in the view, you can try the ajax.

Comment: when I change dropdown value I am calling javascript method '$('#EmployeesEmpId').change' , it calls Action method, but it doesn't bind checkboxes which I want to bind on dropdown index change

Answer (score 0):

Below is a suggestion: to create a patial view to diplay the role, you can refer to it.

_rolepartialView:

```
@model EmpTest.ViewModel.UserRoleViewModel
<div>
    @for (var i = 0; i <= Model.lstRoleAddViewModels.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.lstRoleAddViewModels[i].Checked" />
        <label asp-for="@Model.lstRoleAddViewModels[i].Checked">@Model.lstRoleAddViewModels[i].RoleName</label>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.lstRoleAddViewModels[i].RoleId" />
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.lstRoleAddViewModels[i].RoleName" />
        <br />
    }
</div>
```

In controller  call the _rolepartailView:

```
 [HttpGet]
public IActionResult AddUserRole(int UserId = 0)
{
    UserRoleViewModel userRoleviewmodel = new UserRoleViewModel();

    if (UserId == 0)
    {
        var users = _employeeRepository.GetUsers();
        ViewBag.Users = users;
        userRoleviewmodel.lstRoleAddViewModels = _employeeRepository.UserRoles();
    }
    else if (UserId > 0)
    {
        userRoleviewmodel = _employeeRepository.GetUserRole(UserId);
        return PartialView("_rolepartialView", userRoleviewmodel);
    }

    return View(userRoleviewmodel);
}
```

Then in the view use ajax to display the role, add `id="divToUpdated"`:

```
 <div id="divToUpdated">
     @for (var i = 0; i <= Model.lstRoleAddViewModels.Count - 1; i++)
     {
         <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.lstRoleAddViewModels[i].Checked" />
         <label asp-for="@Model.lstRoleAddViewModels[i].Checked">@Model.lstRoleAddViewModels[i].RoleName</label>
         <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.lstRoleAddViewModels[i].RoleId" />
         <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.lstRoleAddViewModels[i].RoleName" />
         <br />
     }
 </div>
...
 <script>
 $('#EmployeesEmpId').change(function () {
     debugger;
     var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "Employee/AddUserRole";
     var source = '#EmployeesEmpId';
     // $.getJSON(url, { UserId: $(source).val() }, function (data) {
     //     // var items = '';         
     // });
     $.ajax({
         type: 'Get',
         url: '@Url.Content("~/")' + "Employee/AddUserRole",

         data: { UserId: $(source).val() },
         success: function (data) {
             $("#divToUpdated").html(data);
         }

     });
 });
```

**Note** this way will cause the problem when you select `<option value="">Select</option>` to display the view again.

To create an action to call _rolepartialView will avoid the problem:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Update(int UserId)
{UserRoleViewModel userRoleviewmodel = new UserRoleViewModel();

    if (UserId == 0)
    {
        var users = _employeeRepository.GetUsers();
        ViewBag.Users = users;
        userRoleviewmodel.lstRoleAddViewModels = _employeeRepository.UserRoles();
    }
    else if (UserId > 0)
    {
        userRoleviewmodel = _employeeRepository.GetUserRole(UserId);
    }

     return PartialView("_rolepartialView", userRoleviewmodel);}
```

And in the view add ajax like:

```
 <script>
     $('#EmployeesEmpId').change(function () {
         debugger;
         var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "Home/Update";
         var source = '#EmployeesEmpId';
         // $.getJSON(url, { UserId: $(source).val() }, function (data) {
         //     // var items = '';

         // });
         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: '@Url.Content("~/")' + "Home/Update",

             data: { UserId: $(source).val() },
             success: function (data) {
                 $("#divToUpdated").html(data);
             }

         });
     });

 </script>
```

Comment: Hi @Rahul Aggarwal , any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue?
 If not, could you please follow up to let me know?